# ValueError at /cart/add/3 "<Cart: None>" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used

Tags: django, many-to-many, cart, valueerror

I am trying to make acart component for my ecommerce site
this error appears:ValueError at /cart/delete/2
"" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, reverse
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from .models import Cart
from products.models import Product
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
def cart_home(request):
    cart_obj, new_obj=Cart.objects.new_or_get(request) 
    return render(request, "carts/home.html", {"cart":cart_obj})

def addproduct(request, id):
    productobj= get_object_or_404(Product, id=id)

    shoppingcart=Cart()

    shoppingcart.products.add(productobj)
    shoppingcart.save()
    return redirect("carts:home")
def removeproduct(request, id):
    productobj= get_object_or_404(Product, id=id)
    shoppingcart=Cart()
    shoppingcart.products.remove(productobj)
    shoppingcart.save()
    return redirect("carts:home")
```

''''
models.py
''''

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from products.models import Product
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save, post_save, m2m_changed


User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
class CartManager(models.Manager):
    def new_or_get(self, request):
        cart_id = request.session.get("cart_id", None)
        qs      = self.get_queryset().filter(id=cart_id)
        if qs.count() == 1:
            new_obj = False
            print('cart id exists')
            cart_obj = qs.first()
            if request.user.is_authenticated and cart_obj.user is None:
                cart_obj.user = request.user
                cart_obj.save()
        else:
            print("new cart created")
            new_obj = True
            cart_obj= Cart.objects.new(user=request.user)
            request.session['cart_id'] = cart_obj.id
        return cart_obj, new_obj

    def new(self, user=None):
        user_obj = None
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_authenticated:
                user_obj = user_obj
        return self.model.objects.create(user=user_obj)
class Cart(models.Model):

    user        = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete="Cascade")
    products    = models.ManyToManyField(Product, blank=True, null=True)
    total       = models.DecimalField(default=0.00, max_digits=100, decimal_places=2)
    updated     = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    timestamp   = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    objects = CartManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
def m2m_changed_cart_receiver(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    products = instance.products.all()
    total=0
    for x in products:
        total += x.price
    print(total)
    instance.total = total
m2m_changed.connect(m2m_changed_cart_receiver, sender=Cart.products.through)
```

''''
carts:home.html
''''

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content%}
<h1>Cart</h1>
{% if cart.products.exists %}

            <table class="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">#</th>
              <th scope="col">Product Name</th>
              <th scope="col">Product Price</th>

            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {% for product in cart.products.all %}

            <tr>
              <th scope="row">{{forloop.counter}}</th>
              <td><a href="{{product.get_absolute_url}}">{{product.title}}</a>{% include "products/update_cart.html" %}</td>
              <td>{{product.price}}</td>

            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
            <tr>
              <th colspan="2"></th>

              <th><b>Total:</b>{{cart.total}}</th>
            </tr>

          </tbody>
        </table>
{% else %}
    <div class="lead"> Cart is empty</div>
{% endif %}


{% endblock %}
```

''''
cart-update.html

''''

```
{% if product in cart.products.all %}
    <form action="{% url 'carts:remove' product.id %}" 
                    method="post" style="display: inline;" onsubmit="window.mytest()">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <input type="hidden" name="product_id" 
                        value="{{ product.id }}" />
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                        <span class="fas fa-trash-alt"></span>remove?
                    </button>
            </form> 
  {% else %}
            <form action="{% url 'carts:add' product.id %}" 
                    method="post" style="display: inline;" onsubmit="window.mytest()">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <input type="hidden" name="product_id" 
                        value="{{ product.id }}" />
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                        <span class="fas fa-trash-alt"></span>add to cart
                    </button>
            </form> 
{% endif %}
```

''''
so in product:detail template there is abutton enable me to add this product to cart or delete if it is there
how to solve the above error also how to make button go to determined view? thanks in advance>>>

Comment: Please provide the full traceback. I'm assuming this has to do with the object being used before being saved, meaning it hasn't had time to generate its ID yet.

Comment: ValueError at /cart/delete/2
"<Cart: None>" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/cart/delete/2
Django Version: 2.1.5
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value: 
"<Cart: None>" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.
Exception Location: /home/zynaboo/Desktop/dev/ecommerce/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py in __init__, line 823
Python Executable: /home/zynaboo/Desktop/dev/ecommerce/bin/python

Answer (score 0):

In `cart_home`, you correctly use `Cart.objects.new_or_get` to get or create the Cart. But in the other views you just use `Cart()`; that simply instantiates a new unsaved cart, hence the error. You need to use `new_or_get` there too.

Comment: so what if I need to not use new_or_get function >> i need to delete it how can i handle that without this function?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Neither of those views are for deleting the cart. If you want to delete a cart, you probably need a method that just does the "get" part without creating a new one if not found.

Comment: yes, you are right , so when trying to slove problem as following:

Answer (score 0):

```
def cart_home(request):
    cart_obj, new_obj=Cart.objects.new_or_get(request) 
    return render(request, "carts/home.html", {"cart":cart_obj})

def addproduct(request, id):
    productobj= get_object_or_404(Product, id=id)

    shoppingcart=Cart.objects.new_or_get(request)

    shoppingcart.products.add(productobj)
    shoppingcart.save()
    return redirect("carts:home")
def removeproduct(request, id):
    productobj= get_object_or_404(Product, id=id)
    shoppingcart=Cart.objects.new_or_get(request)
    shoppingcart.products.remove(productobj)
    shoppingcart.save()
    return redirect("carts:home")
```

this error appears:
AttributeError at /cart/delete/1
'tuple' object has no attribute 'products'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/cart/delete/1
Django Version: 2.1.5
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:
'tuple' object has no attribute 'products'
Exception Location: /home/zynaboo/Desktop/dev/ecommerce/src/carts/views.py in removeproduct, line 26
Python Executable:  /home/zynaboo/Desktop/dev/ecommerce/bin/python
Python Version: 3.6.7
Python Path:
['/home/zynaboo/Desktop/dev/ecommerce/src',
 '/home/zynaboo/Desktop/dev/ecommerce/lib/python36.zip',
 '/home/zynaboo/Desktop/dev/ecommerce/lib/python3.6',
 '/home/zynaboo/Desktop/dev/ecommerce/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python3.6',
 '/home/zynaboo/Desktop/dev/ecommerce/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
Server time:    Wed, 10 Apr 2019 13:26:56 +0000

Comment: `new_or_get` returns a tuple of `cart, new`.